# How to display shopping cart at the right of page

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to use HTML and css, and want to add a shopping cart at the right side just below the 
menu1, menu2, menu3, menu 4 bar, but do not know how to do it, I was trying to do a .description definition in the css but had no luck  I have a simulation of this, of course i cant upload images which are in images folder...
http://cssizer.com/build/preview/wzNqVAyI
and here is the source 
http://cssizer.com/JKQLGFIM

So I am trying to make the description definition appear just below the menu bar and after that an image of a shopping cart , but do not know how to define it well, How should I modify the code to get something like this

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: I removed the "optimization" tag, as it doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a cart icon on the right side of your website, Hear are the html codes.

```
<div id="head">
<div id="head-one">
<h1>TOM TOC</h1>
<h2>Slogan de </h2></div>
<div id="head-two"><img src="http://c.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/stickers_icon_set/png/64x64/shopping_cart.png" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Hear are the css codes.

```
#head-one{float:left; width:700px;} 
#head-two{float:right; width:70px;} 
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Guess it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

hi now add `overflow:hidden` in your `#nav id`

as like this

```
#nav{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

*result is***

Comment: Is there a way to put an image below that text, How to add that, supossing the image is in directory /images/shopping_cart.jpg ? When I try to add something like .descriptions .shopping_cart {
  
background: url("../images/shopping_cart.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
} is not working